# Does Calico work with Docker in Swarm Mode, If so what is the version?

Tags: docker, calico

Does any one of know which version of calico works with Docker in Swarm Mode?

Answer (score 0):

Per https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_network/ :
Docker 1.12 adds support for cluster management and orchestration called swarm mode. Docker Engine running in swarm mode currently only supports the built-in overlay driver for networking. Therefore existing networking plugins will not work in swarm mode.

I have heard this may be fixed for the upcoming 1.13.1 - so this could change very soon.

Comment: I'm running into this error `Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = legacy plugin calico of type NetworkDriver is not supported in swarm mode` on 1.13.1

Answer (score 0):

In order to work in swarm-mode, the calico plugin must be implemented as a managed plugin.
Calico project should also be swarm-mode compatible and support it.
Some more discussion here https://github.com/projectcalico/calicoctl/issues/1133 on expecting version Calico v2.3.0, Calico v2.2.0, but there is no official confirmation on that.
Though expectation was with Docker 1.13, no official confirmation or documentation on this.
Hope that help